# `router.outlet` is not a function on solid-js `1.7.3` and solid-app-router `0.4.2`

Tags: javascript, typescript, solid-js

I tried to restart my app after making no changes to my code and I suddently got the error below, everything broke suddently and I cannot determine where the issue could come from.

I get the following error which prevents my router from working, I do not undersand where I could come from even if I suppose solid-js or solid-app-router is the source of the problem:

```
uncaught TypeError: route.outlet is not a function
    at get children [as children] (components.jsx:57:64)
    at Object.fn (dev.js:995:35)
    at runComputation (dev.js:696:22)
    at updateComputation (dev.js:679:3)
    at createMemo (dev.js:250:10)
    at children (dev.js:577:20)
    at dev.js:995:14
    at untrack (dev.js:434:12)
    at Object.fn (dev.js:991:36)
    at runComputation (dev.js:696:22)
get children @ components.jsx:5
```

I have the following packages installed on my project:

```
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@interactjs/types": "^1.10.17",
    "@tauri-apps/cli": "^1.2.3",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
    "sass": "^1.62.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "vite": "^4.2.1",
    "vite-plugin-solid": "^2.7.0",
    "vite-plugin-solid-svg": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emailjs/browser": "^3.11.0",
    "@johanmnto/crypto": "^1.0.0",
    "@johanmnto/query": "^1.1.7",
    "@johanmnto/testings": "^1.1.0",
    "@motionone/solid": "^10.16.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.52.1",
    "@tauri-apps/api": "^1.2.0",
    "@types/qrcode-svg": "^1.1.1",
    "@types/sortablejs": "^1.15.1",
    "@vercel/analytics": "^0.1.11",
    "html2pdf.js": "^0.10.1",
    "image-conversion": "^2.1.1",
    "interactjs": "^1.10.17",
    "qrcode-svg": "^1.1.0",
    "solid-app-router": "^0.4.2",
    "solid-js": "^1.7.3",
    "sortablejs": "^1.15.0",
    "stripe": "^8.222.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

After investigating deeper, I found out that the issue was due to `solid-app-router` being now deprecated in favor of `@solidjs/router`.

Comment: Updating @solidjs/router to the latest (currently 0.8.2) fixed it for me, thanks!